# set values on the auth::user controller laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So far my laravel site login worked with default laravel login attempt function,
As per new reuqirment, here after login checking will be performed by third party api,
after successful authentication checking, application will redirect to home page.

in my application lot of place, i have used " Auth " controller variable value. (ie)  Auth::user()->name, Auth::guest() etc.

Due to third party checking i could not able get value on this " Auth " controller, when i try to print Auth::user()->name, i am getting empty value, now please advise how to set values to  Auth::user()->name etc after third party login checking.

Please advice

Got solution

```
$user =User::firstByAttributes(['email' => $email]);
Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: Please add the code your third part that  do"after login checking"

Comment: got solution using below snippet, thanks to every one. $user =User::firstByAttributes(['email' => $email]);
Auth::login($user);